# 2nd ng-repeat-modal-btn not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

I want to have an ng-repeat that contains 2 buttons that opens 2 different modals. My problem is the first button successfully opens its modal but the second one does not.

here is my html

```
<div class="column" ng-repeat="eventObj in events" ng-repeat-dimmer>
  ...
  <button class="circular ui icon green button" id="edit-event"  data-inverted="" data-variation="tiny basic" ng-click="getCurrent(eventObj)" ng-repeat-modal-btn></button>
  <button class="circular ui icon red button" id="delete-event" data-inverted="" data-variation="tiny basic" ng-click="getCurrent(eventObj)" ng-repeat-modal-btn></button>
  ...
</div>
```

and here are my two modals

```
<div class="ui edit-event modal">
<i class="close icon"></i>
  ...
  <form>
    ...
    <div class="field">
     <button class="ui button" type="submit" ng-click="editEvent()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="ui delete-event modal">
<div class="header">Delete Event</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="ui form content">
    Are you sure you want to delete {{eventObj.eventName}}?
  </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <div class="ui green button" ng-click="deleteEvent(eventObj,$event)">Delete Event</div>
  <div class="ui black cancel button">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

Again, I'd like to know why my second button does not work while the first  does, thank you!

Comment: Please create a plunker/fiddle replicating the scenario.

Comment: I have found my error, I checked my js again and it seems that I forgot to update my directive for the 2nd button. I am sorry for this careless mistake. Thank you for your time though.